# Converted Keras model fails calling from experimental iOS TFLite interpreter

Tags: swift, tensorflow, keras

I'm using the experimental TensorFlow Lite Swift cocoapod to try to run a converted Keras model in iOS but I always get a result which is approximately zero (e.g. `[4.2580778e-32]`) for whichever model I try.

Several TensorFlow models that I've converted to TensorFlow Lite work fine in Swift, it just seems to be the Keras models that don't work in Swift but they work fine when I test them in Python.

Here's a super simple bit of example code which does the following:

- create Keras model (which I don't even train, it's just randomly initialized)
- make a test data array and get a prediction from the model
- write the Keras model to a file
- import that model to the TFLite converter and write out a TFLite converted file
- test the TFLite file by loading it to an interpreter and testing on the same test data array from above

```py
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Flatten

# create the model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(32, input_shape=(10,128)))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

# create a test data array matching input shape with batch size of 1, filled with ones
test_data = np.empty((1,10,128), dtype=np.float32)
test_data.fill(1)
print(model.predict(test_data))
# above print produces [[0.20321347]] from random initialization

# write Keras model to a file, also prepare a path for the TFLite file
target_path = 'SimpleTest'
h5_path = 'Models/' + target_path + '.h5'
tflite_path = 'Models/converted_' + target_path + '.tflite'
model.save(h5_path)

# use TFLite converter to write to file
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model_file(h5_path)
tflite_model = converter.convert()
open(tflite_path, "wb").write(tflite_model)

# Load TFLite model and allocate tensors.
interpreter = tf.lite.Interpreter(model_path=tflite_path)
interpreter.allocate_tensors()

# Get input and output tensors.
input_details = interpreter.get_input_details()
output_details = interpreter.get_output_details()
print(input_details, output_details)
# Test model on input data
interpreter.set_tensor(input_details[0]['index'], test_data)
interpreter.invoke()
output_data = interpreter.get_tensor(output_details[0]['index'])
print(output_data)

# The above print statements print [{'name': 'dense_1_input', 'index': 5, 'shape': array([  1,  10, 128], dtype=int32), 'dtype': <class 'numpy.float32'>, 'quantization': (0.0, 0)}] [{'name': 'dense_2/Sigmoid', 'index': 8, 'shape': array([1, 1], dtype=int32), 'dtype': <class 'numpy.float32'>, 'quantization': (0.0, 0)}]
# [[0.2032134]]
```

You can see that the output from the TFLite model very closely matches that from the original Keras model.  So far so good- the TFLite model works perfectly in Python.

In Swift, I have the following code inside a class's init:

```
do{
    var options = InterpreterOptions()
    options.isErrorLoggingEnabled = true
    try self.interpreter = Interpreter(modelPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: modelFileName, ofType: "tflite")!, options: options)
    // allocate input tensors at the given shapes
    try self.interpreter.allocateTensors()
}catch {
    print("initialize TF interpreter failed: \(error)")
    return nil
}

let data = Data(copyingBufferOf: Array<Float>(repeating: 1, count: 128*10))
try interpreter.copy(data, toInputAt: 0)
try interpreter.invoke()
let outputTensor = try interpreter.output(at: 0)
let outputResult = [Float](unsafeData: outputTensor.data)!
print("interpreter result on test data", outputResult)
precondition(outputResult == [0.2032134])
```

The problem is that instead of a value approximately equal to the expected value, I get something close to zero.  This same Swift code works perfectly with a plain TensorFlow model.  There are extensions to Data used above to convert to/from arrays, but they don't seem to be the problem since they work with TFLite models that were created from plain TF models just fine.

Any ideas why various TensorFlow models converted to TFLite work fine in Swift using the TensorFlowLiteSwift cocoapod, but various Keras models converted to TFLite work fine in Python and produce a number approximately zero in Swift?

Comment: Did you solve it?

Comment: @RoiMulia sorry, I did not solve this directly.  I simply built my model without using Keras and it worked fine.  Kind of a pain because it was easier to write/train the model in Keras, but once you have a working model converting it to plain TensorFlow isn't usually that hard.